# Starting point of navigator Highstocks

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've read almost everithing in Highstock Api, but still can't get to how do I set Navigator starting point?

Here is an example. I have big chart with compare, with Navigator, that starts since the very beginning:

[image]

As you see, navigator shows the full history. What I need is a chart, that will initially show just part of series. Navigator should be set on 1st of january 2006.

Here is what I need:

[image]

I've tried pointStart in series, but it does not do what I want, it just cuts series.
Effect, that I want can be achieved, if we put the following:

```
rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },
```

But the problem is, that **I need to start with a specific date**, not a specific range. And range selector should be disabled.

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyM48/). **Pls help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the chart the way you want, but there is a workaround, all you need is an reference to the chart.

Once created the chart the next thing to do is to manualy set the extremes.

```
myChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1262304000000,myChart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max);
```

That number that you see there is the extended(with miliseconds) timestamp for 2010-01-01 00:00:00

JsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/VyM48/2/

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. It was pretty simple, but not well documented.

```
xAxis: {
            min: 1262304000000
        },
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyM48/3/)